# Where does TempData get stored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

Where does TempData get stored in the ASP.NET MVC Framework (more specifically, ASP.NET MVC 2)? Is it stored at server-side, or is sent to the client?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default TempData uses the ASP.NET Session as storage. So it is stored on the server (`InProc` is the default). But you could define other ASP.NET Session state modes: StateServer and SqlServer. You could also write a custom TempData provider and handle the storage yourself if you don't want to use the ASP.NET Session.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will investigate more about the ASP.NET session state modes, that's new for me.

Comment: This seems not to be true anymore for ASP.NET Core.
"The cookie-based TempData provider is enabled by default. To enable the session-based TempData provider... "
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 14):

It is stored in session storage, but there is one crucial difference between `TempData` and `Session`:

`TempData` is available **only for a user’s session**, so it persists **only till we have read it** and gets cleared at the end of an HTTP Request.

A scenario that fits the usage of `TempData`, is when data needs to persist between two requests – a redirect scenario. Another scenario I can think of is to return an error message after a POST operation fails.

Comment: Thanks man, I wish I could select more than one answer as accepted.

Comment: *TempData is available only for a user’s session, so it persists only till we have read it and gets cleared at the end of an HTTP Request.* Sessions last longer than HTTP requests. So is *TempData is available only for a user's session* correct?